# Maching the figcaption with picture through css and html

Tags: css

In this codes, I am trying to write a caption for each picture. Except the first picture and its caption, the caption for pic 2 and 3 do not comply with their css codes. I really appreciate if let me about my mistake.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css" media="all">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>First website</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
  <div id="main-menu">
   <a href="#Markup languages and scripting"> M&S </a>
   <a href="#Health & saftely issues when working with computers"> Health&Saftely </a>
   <span id="dropbtn">
    <button id="clickable-button">U&C</button>
      <div id="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#1">Statistics and backgroud information</a>
        <a href="#2">Research groups / research projects</a>
        <a href="#3">Courses</a>
      </div>
   </span>
   <a href="aboutUs.html"> About us </a>
  </div>
  </header>
  <section>
    <div id="text-aboutUs">
      <p>In this page, you can find some information regarding to each member of this group. This information includes their personal interests, hobbies and some other intriguing information about the selected person. In order to access the information you just need to click on your intended person.</p> 
      <figure>
       <a href="#123"> <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/27714/pexels-photo-27714.jpg" width="300" height="350" alt="Hossein's photo" ></a>
       <figcaption> Jack Ferreni</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div id="pic2">
      <figure>
        <a href="#123"> <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/27714/pexels-photo-27714.jpg" width="300" height="350" alt="Hossein's photo" ></a>
       <figcaption>Jack Ferreni</figcaption>
      </figure>
     </div>
     <div id="pic3">
      <figure>
        <a href="#123"> <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/27714/pexels-photo-27714.jpg" width="300" height="350" alt="Hossein's photo" ></a>
       <figcaption> Jack Ferreni</figcaption>
      </figure>
     </div>
  </section>
  <footer> 


</body>
```

CSS code:

```
body{
      background-color:#333333;
    }
header{
        background-color:black; 
        margin-left:200px;
        margin-right:200px;
        margin-top:20px;
        padding-top:100px;
      }
section{
        background-color:#eff8fb; 
        margin-left:200px;
        margin-right:200px;
        border:10px solid black;
        padding-bottom:20px;
       } 
footer{
        background-color:black; 
        margin-left:200px;
        margin-right:200px;
        margin-bottom:20px;
        padding-bottom:100px;
        border:10px solid black;
       }
#text-aboutUs > p{
                  color:black;
                  padding-left:30px;
                  padding-right:15px;
                  padding-top:0px;
                  margin-top:0px;
                 }
#text-aboutUs > P:first-letter{
                               font-size:3em;
                              }
#text-aboutUs > figure > a > img{
                                  position: absolute;
                                  left:500px;
                                  top:270px;
                                }
#text-aboutUs > figure > a > img:hover{
                                    border:10px ridge black;
                                  }
#text-aboutUs >  figure > figcaption{
                                     margin-left:300px;
                                     margin-top:420px;
                                     font-family:sans-serif;
                                     font-style:italic;
                                     font-size:20px;
                                    }
#pic2 > figure > a > img{
                          position:relative;
                          top:50px;
                          left:140px;
                          padding-bottom:130px;

                        }
#pic2 > figure > a > img:hover{
                                    border:10px ridge black;
                              }
#pic2 >  figure > figcaption{        
                               margin-top:0px;    
                               margin-left:400px;
                               font-family:sans-serif;
                               font-style:italic;
                               font-size:20px;
                             }
#pic3 > figure > a > img{
                          position: absolute;
                          left:1100px;
                           top:270px;
                        }
#pic3 > figure > a > img:hover{
                                    border:10px ridge black;
                              }
#pic3 >  figure > figcaption{  
                              margin-left:600px;
                              margin-top:0px
                              font-family:sans-serif;
                              font-style:italic;
                              font-size:20px;
                             }
```

Comment: What is the issue with the caption you have in your html?...what would you like it to be?

Comment: I want the captions are located exactly bellow each picture, but it does not work when I feed them b css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues affecting that is causing the caption to lay directly underneath the image

You have an image position absolute in the anchor container. As a result the container will only adjust its size to fit the fig caption. Remove this position: absolute

A margin top and left is set on each fig caption. This is causing the caption to distance itself from the image and shift to the right. Remove this too.

Finally add a text-align center to the figure element to align the title beneath the beneath and in the center.

See snippet below

```css
body {
  background-color: #333333;
}

header {
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  background-color: #eff8fb;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

footer {
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  border: 10px solid black;
}

#text-aboutUs>p {
  color: black;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
figure{
text-align: center;
}

#text-aboutUs>P:first-letter {
  font-size: 3em;
}

#text-aboutUs>figure>a>img {}

#text-aboutUs>figure>a>img:hover {
  border: 10px ridge black;
}

#text-aboutUs>figure>figcaption {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#pic2>figure>a>img {
  position: relative;
}

#pic2>figure>a>img:hover {
  border: 10px ridge black;
}

#pic2>figure>figcaption {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#pic3>figure>a>img:hover {
  border: 10px ridge black;
}

#pic3>figure>figcaption {
  margin-left: 600px;
  margin-top: 0px font-family:sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css" media="all">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>First website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div id="main-menu">
      <a href="#Markup languages and scripting"> M&S </a>
      <a href="#Health & saftely issues when working with computers"> Health&Saftely </a>
      <span id="dropbtn">
    <button id="clickable-button">U&C</button>
      <div id="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#1">Statistics and backgroud information</a>
        <a href="#2">Research groups / research projects</a>
        <a href="#3">Courses</a>
      </div>
   </span>
      <a href="aboutUs.html"> About us </a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section>
    <div id="text-aboutUs">
      <p>In this page, you can find some information regarding to each member of this group. This information includes their personal interests, hobbies and some other intriguing information about the selected person. In order to access the information you
        just need to click on your intended person.</p>
      <figure>
        <a href="#123"> <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/27714/pexels-photo-27714.jpg" width="300" height="350" alt="Hossein's photo"></a>
        <figcaption> Jack Ferreni</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div id="pic2">
      <figure>
        <a href="#123"> <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/27714/pexels-photo-27714.jpg" width="300" height="350" alt="Hossein's photo"></a>
        <figcaption>Jack Ferreni</figcaption>
      </figure>
```